# Eclipse 4.2 and Java 8

Tags: java, eclipse, closures, java-8

I found this [page](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/plans/eclipse_project_plan_4_2.xml) stating that Java 8 support for Juno is deffered, but I can't find more information how soon people can exspect to be able to write first closures in Eclipse and get productive with that stuff.

Has someone got insight how long we still have to wait? The Java7 features were in 3.7 really quickly, that's why it's kind of odd that this task is deferred.

Any comments, ideas? Or maybe even a good workaround?

Comment: are you asking about clojure (the language) Closures (data structures that contain a function and it lexical context)?

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt Thanks, I'm talking about the language extension in Java 8.

Comment: @Franz Kafka: So you are asking about anonymous function literals / lambda expressions (which are going to be introduced in Java 8). Closures (AKA anonymous inner classes) have been in Java for a long time already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the key reasons that Java 8 support was deferred is that Java 8 will be available after Eclipse Juno is released. A major release of Eclipse couldn't be shipped with functionality reliant on an unfinished Java release.

Java 7 support went through a similar issue with Eclipse Indigo. Tooling for Java 7 proceeded in a branch that was merged into main indigo stream after Java 7 shipped, so you saw tooling support in Indigo SR1.

I would expect a similar situation for Java 8. There may be a branch open for this work already. The best place to check in on the status is in the bug that is referenced from the document that you found.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=380190

Comment: and IntelliJ looks like it might be on a [similar roadmap for IntelliJ 12](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5456390#5456390).

Answer (score 7):

Java 8 will be released at some point after mid 2013, so there is still quite some time to go :-)  Full support in Eclipse for Java 8 should not be expected before Java 8's release date, it was the same for Java 7 support.

Currently, there is no branch open for this work. However, whenever that does happen you can expect to see a few blog posts about it :-)

Comment: Unfortunately Java 8 release delayed until March 2014. http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/

Answer (score 3):

You may give IntelliJ Idea a try which has preliminary suport for it, see http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP

Comment: And [Netbeans](http://bertram2.netbeans.org:8080/job/jdk8lambda/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/) as well